# Android ScrollView dont scroll when keyboard appears instead make layout smaller

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

i have a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout. I want the layout scrolls when the keyboard appears but instead the size of the layout will reduced. The following is set in my manifest "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize". Does somebody has any ideas?

[Layout before keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyTMZ.jpg)
[Layout after keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rTri.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorBlack"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Activity_Contact_First"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_Activity_Contact_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/editText_KontaktAufnehmen_Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_Activity_Contact_Issue"
                android:layout_width="308dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_Activity_Contact"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_Activity_Contact"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Activity_Contact_Text"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bordershadow"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Schreib uns dein Anliegen (max. 500 Zeichen)"
                android:maxLength="500"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorTextGray"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Activity_Contact"
                android:layout_width="220sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background_save_mobilenumber"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:text="@string/editText_Kontakt_ButtonAbschicken"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorBlue"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what adjustResize does.  It makes the app resize into the space above the keyboard.  If you want the app to just pan, use adjustPan.  In that case the app will scroll up just enough that the caret is on screen.

Comment: When i set it to adjustPan the keyboard hides the layout. I want that the whole layout scrolls when the keyboard appears.

Comment: @ChrisCologne There is no setting for that.  THat's not something that's a possibility in Android.  The settings are resize, or pan so that caret stays in window